# How to use add/subtract in css propert?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add/subtract in css property?

```
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50% ;
  left: calc(50% - 286px);
  margin-left: -75px /* half of the width */
  background-color: red; /* or something more useful */
  z-index:100;
}
```

I am simply try to add/subtract the contents value in the actual top and left percentage

```
top: 50% - contents_height_in_number_with_px
```

I want to do this so that my main contents is automatically centered 
Note:i already search on googled and already try calc() not found any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That css (`calc()`) is [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc). You need to know the height of the current viewport and the height of div#box. Here's a way to determine both, i.e. to center an element. You can ditch  `top:50% ; left:calc(50% - 286px);margin-left:-75px` in the css now.

```
// get viewport dimensions
function viewport(){
    var  innerw = window.innerWidth
        ,root   = innerw  ? window : (document.body || document.documentElement)
        ,body   = (document.body || document.documentElement)
        ,which  = innerw ? 'inner' : 'client';
    return {  width : root[ which+'Width' ] 
             ,height : root[ which+'Height' ]
             ,scrollTop: body.scrollTop 
             ,scrollLeft: body.scrollLeft };
}

// center an element (uses viewport function)
function center(el){
  var dims = viewport()
     ,l = Math.floor( (0.5*dims.width)-(0.5*el.offsetWidth) )
     ,h = Math.floor( (0.5*dims.height)-(0.5*el.offsetHeight) );
  el.style.left = l+'px';
  el.style.top  = h+'px';
  return true;
}
// usage:
center(document.getElementById('box'));
```

See also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/X5DuY/)

Comment: @kooilnc thank you so much for your solution 
can you please also explain how to use this

Comment: Hi Danish Iqbal, just include both functions in a javascript (.js) file and use `center([someelement]);` to center an element (see `// usage` @ the bottom of the code in the answer). **Note**: [someelement] should be positioned `absolute`.

Comment: Hi,Kooilnc thanks again for your kind cooperation 
i add this line in head tag "<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" and also create a .js file with two above functions but its yet not work

Comment: @Kooilnc please check the question i update my complete file code 
thank you so much for kind favor

Comment: Copy/paste the *complete function text of my answer*, so use one script tag: `<script type="text/javascript">/*PASTE TEXT OF BOTH FUNCTIONS HERE */ center(document.getElementById('box'));</script>`

Comment: Move the complete script tag to the end of the document (right before the closing body tag (`</body>`))

Comment: fantastic man wonderful man wonderful grate 
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi Danish Iqbal, glad I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: @kooilnc hi i found that div is not position currently in ie you can check this here http://www.edu-advisors.com/login.php what do you suggest thanks again

Comment: Hi Danish, in my IE it displays like it should.

Comment: @Kooilnc yes now its work i add condition comment for ie with javascript

Answer (score 3):

Currently this is only supported in IE9 and Firefox 10.  See http://caniuse.com/calc

A better solution for you would likely be less.  http://lesscss.org

If you use a server side language you can even parse it on the fly:

.Net: dotLESS - http://www.dotlesscss.org/
PHP: lessphp - http://leafo.net/lessphp/

.less compiles up to native CSS but allows you to do much more than CSS would normally do.

Comment: Wow, we are finally going to be able to do this in regular CSS? It's about time