# Showing div at the center of the webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a div showing "Please wait". The markup for the div is

`<div id="pleaseWait" class="divOuterPleaseWait" style="left:expression((documentElement.clientWidth-this.offsetWidth)/2);top:expression(documentElement.scrollTop+((documentElement.clientHeight-this.clientHeight)/2 ));">Please Wait...</div>`

This is working fine with IE7. In IE7 the div is show at the center of the page. But excepted behariour is not optained in other browsers (ie. IE8,IE9,FireFox,Google Chrome etc). What should i give to get this working in all browsers? Also can I move the inline style to the my CSS?

Comment: @Pankaj margin:0 auto; works width define width

Comment: Why is width a problem if you're displaying just that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443718/how-to-use-add-subtract-in-css-propert/9443772#9443772), or [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/X5DuY/) (press the 'confirm' button). The css you showed in your question is browser specific (especially: IE). In javascript you can center an element by determining the 'viewport' dimensions (height/width of the available screen) and position your element relative to those dimension. The links here demonstrate a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to center a div is to use fixed positioning, top and left set to 50% and left and top margin to the negative of half of the width/height:

http://jsfiddle.net/fLa4S/

Comment: Exactly, although fixed positioning has some idiosyncrasies in IE 7 (doesn't respect z-index and I've noted drawing bugs).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in "other browsers" because you are using expressions in your CSS which are 1) incredibly bad for a variety of reasons (slow, deprecated, non-standard) and 2) unnecessary.

You can use pure CSS positioning (percentages and negative margins) or a little JavaScript (jQuery makes this very easy) to accomplish the same thing in all browsers.

Comment: The question isn't why this is not work? It's what will make it work. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - see my answer: "percentages and negative margins".

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
<div style="text-align:center;width=200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">Please wait...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS expressions are only working in IE. However, it´s generally not a good idea to use them because they are not W3C conform and in addition they can be very slow when you make heavy use of them.

The CSS attribute position: fixed could help you here:

```
#pleaseWait {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed; /* IE8+ */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px; /* half of width*/
    margin-top: -100px; /* half of height*/
}
```

If you have to still support <=IE7 you have to use JavaScript (but not within the CSS definition!)

Answer (score 0):

Using *auto* as margins and defining a width and hight should be enough

```
<div style="width:200px;height:50px;margin:auto;text-align:center">Please wait ...</div>
```

If you only want to center verticaly, use *margin: 0 auto;*

PS: if you want to be more XHTML-correct, put your CSS in a CSS-file and use a class or a id to define the css-styling

I've answered this before: [How to set the div in center of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180134/how-to-set-the-div-in-center-of-the-page/9180174#9180174)